# How can I Restart Python code when I type a string

Tags: python, restart

```
x = int(input("Type lenght: "))
y = int(input("Type Width: "))

print("IF you wanna find AREA Type Area")
print("IF you wanna find VOLUME Type Volume")

z = str(input("What You wanna find: "))

area = x * y
volume = (x * 2) + (y * 2)

if z == 'Area' or 'area':
    print("Area is ", area)
elif z == 'Volume' or 'volume':
    print("Volume is ", volume)
else:
    print("Something Goes Wrong")

print("You wanna find another value type RESTART")
print("You wanna find another value type CLOSE")

a = str(input())
if a == 'CLOSE' or 'close' or 'Close':
    exit()
```

This is one of my basic python code. if someone types restart, I want to make this code restart.
Do you guys know how to do that

Comment: Make your code into a function. Whenever want to restart. Just call the function.

Comment: You need to introduce a loop of some kind

Comment: you can use `os.system("python path to your script.py")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your code into a function. And make the user select part out of the function. Whenever want to restart. Just call the function.

Here is a template:

```
def myJobFn():
  x = int(input("Type length: "))
  # blah blah blah

arg = "RESTART"
while arg not in ["CLOSE"]:
  if arg == "RESTART":
    myJobFn()
  arg = input("Type 'RESTART' or 'CLOSE'").upper()
```

---

Or just ignore `RESTART` option:

```
arg = None
while arg not in ["CLOSE"]:
  myJobFn()
  arg = input("Type 'CLOSE' for quit").upper()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to address your problem the most easy and quick ones to implement are following

**VERSION 1**

using a infinite loop until you type "close"

```
def Calculate(x, y):
    print("IF you wanna find AREA Type Area")
    print("IF you wanna find VOLUME Type Volume")

    z = str(input("What You wanna find: "))

    area = x * y
    volume = (x * 2) + (y * 2)

    if z == 'Area' or 'area':
        print("Area is ", area)
    elif z == 'Volume' or 'volume':
        print("Volume is ", volume)
    else:
        print("Something Goes Wrong")

    print("You wanna find another value type RESTART")
    print("You wanna find another value type CLOSE")

    a = str(input())
    return a.lower() == 'restart'

while True:
    x = int(input("Type lenght: "))
    y = int(input("Type Width: "))
    if not Calculate(x, y):
        break
```

**Version 2**

Using goto statement

```
from goto import goto, label

label .start
x = int(input("Type lenght: "))
y = int(input("Type Width: "))

print("IF you wanna find AREA Type Area")
print("IF you wanna find VOLUME Type Volume")

z = str(input("What You wanna find: "))

area = x * y
volume = (x * 2) + (y * 2)

if z == 'Area' or 'area':
    print("Area is ", area)
elif z == 'Volume' or 'volume':
    print("Volume is ", volume)
else:
    print("Something Goes Wrong")

print("You wanna find another value type RESTART")
print("You wanna find another value type CLOSE")

a = str(input())
if a == 'CLOSE' or 'close' or 'Close':
    exit()

goto .start
```

**Other versions**
You can obviously do one of the following to repeat

- Using Recursion
- Using Threads

Comment: I'm sure that development of the *goto* module was an interesting exercise but... seriously?

Comment: glad to hear from you but look we are here to highlight different possibilities and solutions, along the best possible, so he has other options too

Answer (score 1):

The code flow needs to be rearranged. You should offer the option to exit immediately (along with the other options). For a simple case like this it's better just to use single-digit options rather than asking user to enter complete words.

The code for calculating volume doesn't seem right so this code adds another input.

```
def getValues(height=False):
    x = float(input('Length: '))
    y = float(input('Width: '))
    z = float(input('Height: ')) if height else None
    return x, y, z


while True:
    match input('1) Area, 2) Volume, 3) Exit: '):
        case '1':
            x, y, _ = getValues()
            print(f'Area = {x*y}')
        case '2':
            x, y, z = getValues(True)
            print(f'Volume = {x*y*z}')
        case '3':
            break
        case _:
            print('Invalid option')
```

**Note:**

You will need Python 3.10+ for this